# How can I move the "C" left using span tag in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Here is my small code, I would like the resulting "C" positioned left about 20px. How can I do this with the span tag? Thanks.

```
if (obj.celsius == "YES"){
var temperatureUnit = "C";
document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML = tempValue+ "&#176;" + temperatureUnit;        
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (obj.celsius == "YES"){
    var temperatureUnit = "C";
    document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML = tempValue+ "&#176;<span style='margin-left: 20px;'>" + temperatureUnit + "</span>";        
}
```

Or make the span have a `.class` and then place the margin your CSS file.